# Organizing tournaments for odd and even number of teams, using modulo

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My professor's notes state that to organize a tournament with an odd number of teams, a fictional team is created. When a team has to play against the fictional one, instead it doesn't play. The formula given for who plays with who on each turn is

$$i + j \equiv k \pmod{N-1}$$

Where i = the number of the team, j is the oponent which you want to find out, N is the total number of teams.

If you have 5 teams, you add an extra team and get this:

[image]

(here "Passa" = "Pass", the top row represents the team number, the leftmost column represents the turn).

I didn't have much trouble doing this, however, I am having trouble doing this for an even number of teams. An exercise asks to do this for 8 teams. I tried to apply the same method. For example, for team 1 , turn one, I'd do

$$1 + j \equiv 1 \pmod 8$$

I wasn't sure whether I should do N-1 or N because the number is even. Either way, it didn't work. The solution is as follows:

[image]

("jogador" = player, "jogada" = turn)

I just can't figure out how to do this. I can't do N - 1 because then I wouldn't get the 8th team. So I assume it's mod 8. But if I do mod 8 for the first team, first turn, I get:

$$1+j \equiv 1 \pmod 8 \\
j \equiv 0 \pmod 8 \\
j = 8$$

The notes are unclear. I'm puzzled. How do I do this?

Comment: really only part that I can't see patterns in yet is where to place 8.

Comment: Looks like modulo $7$ to me. Take the 3rd row. $1+2\equiv2+1\equiv3+7\equiv\cdots\equiv3\bmod7$. There's always one team you can't match this way; for round 3, it's team 5, since the solution to $5+x\equiv3\bmod7$ is $x=5$. The team you can't match is the one you match with team $8$.

Comment: So, what do you think, Silence?

Comment: Are you still here, Silence?

Comment: Not polite to ignore someone who is trying to help you, Silence.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not ignoring, I have just been away. Thanks for the help, I've asked my professor in the meantime and figured it out.

Comment: Good. Then let me encourage you to write it up and post it here as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today.

Comment: Been away again?

Answer (score 0):

In the following, think of 2-3-5-7-8-6-4 as a chain that you rotate one position counterclockwise each day while keeping 1 fixed.

12
34
56
78

--
14
26
38
57

--
16
48
27
35

--
18
67
45
23

--
17
85
63
42

--
15
73
82
64

--
13
52
74
86

--

Comment: I think I am supposed to solve this using modulos...